Map function not returning the expected column (3rd) from array
I'm having an issue retrieving email addresses from the 3rd col in an array (obtained from a Gsheet) using filter and map functions. The call is printing an empty array in the log. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?
Here is the function:
/**
 * Retrieves email addresses from a sheet based on selected names from a form.
 *
 * @param {object} e - Form submit event object.
 * @return {string} - A comma-separated string of email addresses.
 */
function getEmailAddresses(e) {
  // Get the responses from the form.
  const responses = e.response.getItemResponses();

  // Extract the selected names from the checkboxes.
  const eList = responses.find(item => item.getItem().getTitle() === 'E List').getResponse();

  // Get the spreadsheet and sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  const shet = ss.getSheetByName('ECI');

  const data = shet.getRange(2, 1, shet.getLastRow()-1, 3).getValues();

  // Logger.log(data);

  // Filter the data based on selected names and extract email addresses.
  // Assuming first name is in column 1 and last name in column 2
  // Assuming email is in column 3
  const emailAddresses = data.filter(row => eList.includes(`${row[0]} ${row[1]}`)).map(row => row[2]);
  Logger.log(emailAddresses);

  // Return the email addresses as a comma-separated string.
  return emailAddresses.join(',');
}


eList



First
Last
Email
Phone




A
a
A@email.com
12345


B
b
B@email.com
67890


C
c
C@email.com
12346



data



First
Last
Email




A
a
A@email.com


B
b
B@email.com


C
c
C@email.com




If you're getting an empty array, the problem is filter(), not map(). None of the rows match the filtering condition.

Please provide minimal reproducible example in the form of a sample spreadsheet.

We also need a sample value of eList.

I agree with @Barmar. I suspect that the issue has something to do with the .includes method within the map. However, we need more details as to what the data looks like to verify our suspicion.

Thank you both! Please see link
eList = [[A, a, A@email.com],[B, b, B@email.com],[C, c, C@email.com]]
Where I'm hoping to return emailAddresses = [A@email.com,B@email.com,C@email.com]

Unfortunately, the file is inaccessible. It's giving the message that The organization that owns this item doesn't allow you to access it. Instead, you may use Tables to show your data or Make an anonymous sample document as the minimal, reproducible example.

@MikalDChavez [Edit] your question to add the eList and also add data too..

Based from your marked down table, in which column should we expect the checkbox?

The checkboxes are from a Google form, I'm using eList to get an array of the responses to match against data to extract the emails of the users selected

To help the community visualize the questions, please provide a sample of the Google Form. Also, based on what was provided, it seems like the data might be on the same spreadsheet on a separate sheet from the responses. Would that be correct?

elist = [A, a, B, b, C, c]
For some reason I'm not able to edit the table for eList but it only contains First and Last (I think that's where I'm going wrong). I want to check if the names exists in data and if so store the email (the other issue is that eList is a basic array that has both first and last so once one is found for a given user i'd want it to iterate through eList)
eList
|First|Last|
| --- |--- |
| A   | a  |
| B   | b  |
| C   | c  |

Assuming that the data you have actually looks like what you provided in your comment, this should do what you want.
UPDATE:
Here is a more complex solution that should result in what you want, there's a lot of room for improvement here such as memoizing the makeUserHash function, and better error handling.
Depending on the sizes of these lists, doing a .filter inside a .map will cause you to iterate through the full eList many times.
Here I loop through eList once, and make a flat array of hashes on the data we want, then iterate through the data list once, make the userHash and check if it's in the eListHashes.  Since we use the same hashing function, and the same data set for each user, they'll return the same values.  Additionally, if we have the user data, but not the email, we can find it from the initial eList array.


// Updated based on comment;

// Helper Fucntions
const makeHash = (string) => {
    if (typeof string !== 'string') string = JSON.stringify(string);
  string = string.toLowerCase();

    let hash = 0;

    if (string.length === 0) return hash;
    let index = 0;
    do {
        hash = (hash << 5) - hash + string.charCodeAt(index);
        hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
        index++;
    } while (index < string.length);

    return hash.toString();
};

const makeUserHash = (item) => {
  if (!item?.[0] || !item?.[1]) return false;
  const user = {
    firstName: item[0],
    lastName: item[1],
  }
  return makeHash(user);
};

const eList = [
  ['A', 'a', 'A@email.com', '12345'],
  ['B', 'b', 'B@email.com', '12345'],
  ['C', 'c', 'C@email.com', '12345'],
  ['D', 'd', 'D@email.com', '12345'],
  ['E', 'e', 'E@email.com', '12345'],
];

const eListHashes = eList.map((listItem) => makeUserHash(listItem));

console.log(eListHashes);


const data = [
  ['A', 'a', 'A@email.com'],
  ['B', 'b', 'B@email.com'],
  ['C', 'c', 'C@email.com'],
  ['D', 'd'],
  ['F', 'f', 'F@email.com'],
];

const emailAddresses = data.map((listItem) => {
  const userHash = makeUserHash(listItem);
  
  const userMatch = eListHashes.includes(userHash);
  const haveEmail = listItem?.[2];
  
  if (userMatch && haveEmail) return haveEmail;
  if (userMatch && !haveEmail) {
    const eListIndex = eListHashes.indexOf(userHash);
    const eListEntry = eList[eListIndex];
    
    const haveEListEmail = eListEntry?.[2]
    return haveEListEmail ? haveEListEmail : false;
  }
  
  return false;
}).filter(Boolean);

console.log('emailAddresses: ', emailAddresses);




Thank you, this works but is extracting all the emails in data. E List is a Google Form that has checkboxs with the name of each user in eList. I was hoping to only extract the ones that match the selected users from the eList and combine them into a string. This was the following ln
const emailAddresses = data.filter(row => eList.includes(${row[0]} ${row[1]})).map(row => row[2]);

Sorry for the misunderstanding, it's hard for me to understand without a MRE.  I've just updated my answer with more context.   I am now returning an array of emails, from users in both lists.

Here is elist = [A, a, B, b, C, c] I only want to return the emails of all associated users in data. Since both first and last name would match in elist, I would only want to store that user's email once if they're name matches (I'd want first and last to match since some people could have the same first and/or last name)

To get matching values you need to  iterate eList for every row of data:
const emailAddresses = data.filter(row => eList.some(fRow => row[0] === fRow[0] && row[1] === fRow[1])).map(row => row[2]);

The double iteration is achieved through .filter on the data and .some on the eList, comparing only firstnames([0]) and last names([1]). if eList has many rows, it maybe wise to create a Set of eListNames and eListEmailAddresses for comparison. I assume eList is small compared to data and therefore prefer the lazy double loop as shown above.

Thank you for your help. I have tried this approach and it's producing an empty array. The following line is returning the emails but isn't filtering for only the ones that matched first and last name selected from the form const emailAddresses = data.map((row) => row[2] || false).filter(Boolean);

@MikalDChavez Could you add console.log(JSON.stringify(eList)) and console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) to your question with small sample size?

I tested the answer's script, and assuming that the Google Form responses are similar to this sample image and the ECI sheet, which contains the data, is similar to this sample image, it should return something like this sample output. Since it's still not working for you, please provide all relevant details in producing an empty array. to  replicate the issue.
